# Cant find Thinkpad x230 keyboard layout

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-layout, thinkpad

I bought the used x230, for cheap in Austria.

After peeling of the keyboard stickers that came with the laptop, what I thought was a Swiss keyboard turned out to be something else I cannot find.

It matches neither the French  nor Belgian layouts too. Anybody with insight into the same?

[image]

**EDIT**

So thanks to @allquixotic I figured the seller had swapped the keys. I redid them to their rightful places and found out its a french keyboard.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was unable to find a picture of this specific keyboard layout [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QWERTZ), but I *was* able to figure out that the *keys* are from the French [AZERTY layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AZERTY); however, they seem to be reordered, like someone pulled up the keys themselves or the labels and (mis)placed them.

When in doubt, I usually go back to the handy keyboard detector tool from Ubuntu (which you can use on any keyboard that has the same number/placement of keys as the keyboard layout you're trying to identify). Here's what I did:

- Fire up VMware Workstation and create a new VM
- Put the Ubuntu Server 16.04.3 ISO in it and boot it up
- The installer first asks you to go through keyboard layout detection!

However, it asks for a key that doesn't exist on your keyboard based on the input I give it, which tells me that either (1) this layout doesn't actually exist as arranged on your keycap labels, or (2) Ubuntu isn't aware of it (the latter is somewhat unlikely, as Ubuntu supports hundreds of keyboard layouts).

[image: animated gif of keyboard layout detection]

My guess: it's either a special "rearranged AZERTY" (very non-standard, far as I can tell) French keyboard, or someone (you, or the original owner) has played around with the keycaps and created a keyboard layout that doesn't actually exist.

Answer (score -1):

It's the [QWERTZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QWERTZ) layout - which is used in Germany and Austria, which makes a lot of sense. Some of the oddities - like the symbolic caps lock could be attributed to that, although there are a few oddities here.

[image: enter link description here]

<sub>source: CC BY-SA 3.0, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=1058095</sub>

This matches the layout and original place you bought it at perfectly.

(Amusingly, the one place I've seen this in the wild was at a cybercafe at the French/Italian border.)

Comment: But you see the deadkey activated symbols and special buttons such as Supprimer and the touche Échap showed its French origins no?

Comment: ooh, super strange. I didn't quite notice those.

Comment: Me too at first. Thats why deduced it was a Swiss keyboard in the beginning. But thanks for the input. It makes the question richer for future searchers